Unity: Accessing a button text value for a dynamic avatar assignation in a CharacterSelectionScript
Hello everyone i was trying to do a simple avatar assignation by using a dynamic prefab starter in the network manager. unfortunately i have some problems on accessing the value of a gender button that changes its text value everytime someone presses it. The button is in the scene but the dynamic prefab starter is not. How can I do it?
public class characterSpawner : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private NetworkObject prefabMale;
    [SerializeField] private NetworkObject prefabFemale;
 
    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        //Button yourButton = yourObject.GetComponent<Button>();
        string buttonText = "Female";
 
        Button btn = (Button)FindObjectOfType(typeof(Button));
 
        if (!IsServer) {  return; }
 
        if(buttonText == "Male")
        {
            var spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-3f, 3f), 0f, Random.Range(-3f, 3f));
            var characterInstance = Instantiate(prefabMale, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
           
        }
        else
        {
 
            var spawnPos = new Vector3(Random.Range(-3f, 3f), 0f, Random.Range(-3f, 3f));
            var characterInstance = Instantiate(prefabFemale, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
 
        }
 
    }
}

I tried some stuff such as accessing via a [serializedvar] the button but since this script is associated to the prefab in the networkmanager and is not in the scene it can't see the button. I tried to do a "GetBtnValue" method in another script associated to a ServerManager in the scene but also for some reasons don't work.

Solved by adding a getValue in a script attached to a SceneManager, inside the scene and setting a variable that changes every time the button is pressed.
